# how to pass JSON object from html to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, handlebars.js

Below is my code:

```
  <script id="product-listing" type="x-handlebars-template">
     {{#each productsInCart}}
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="imageDiv">
                        <img id="productImg" src="src/{{p_id}}.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Product Image" >                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>{{p_name}}</span><br>
                    <span>Style #: {{p_style}}</span><br>
                    <span>COLOR: </span>
                    <div style="margin-top:15%;">
                        <span id="spnEdit" onclick="openEditModel('{{p_available_options.colors}}','{{p_id}}');">EDIT</span> 
                            <!--<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">EDIT</a>-->
                        <span>REMOVE</span>

                        <span>SAVE FOR LATER</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{p_selected_size.code}}</td>
                <td>{{p_quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{c_currency}} {{p_price}}</td>
              </tr>
              {{/each}}
              </script>
```

I am facing issue while passing a JSON object in a function `openEditModel('{{p_available_options.colors}}','{{p_id}}')`. The `{{p_available_options.colors}}` returning `[object object]`.
Note: `{{p_available_options.colors.[0].hexcode}}` getting the value but I need whole set of data.

The snippet of my JSON is attached here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNHMv.png) 
Can anyone help me with this.

```
   "p_available_options": {
        "colors": [{
            "name": "green",
            "hexcode": "#A3D2A1"
        }, {
            "name": "yellow",
            "hexcode": "#F9F8E6"
        }, {
            "name": "red",
            "hexcode": "#ED99A8"
        }],
        "sizes": [{
            "name": "small",
            "code": "s"
        }, {
            "name": "medium",
            "code": "m"
        }, {
            "name": "large",
            "code": "l"
        }, {
            "name": "extra large",
            "code": "xl"
        }]
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Dhiraj

Comment: Please edit your post and incorporate the snippet of your JSON code into a `code section` of your question.

Comment: I've added the JSON snippet over here. It would be great if you could suggest me anything on this.

Comment: function openEditModel(x,img){
 console.log(x);// Here I am getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. I've tried JSON.strinify(), jQuery.parseJSON()  but non of them worked for me.
 $("#modalImg").attr("src", "src/"+img+".jpg")
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
 $('#editAddModalBtn').html("EDIT");
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using handlebars to populate the data. 
Inspect the html and see if json is within the tag - based on your testing handlebars isn't handling the object population.

I would read handlebars documentation of how to render json objects raw OR before you populate the object convert it into a string on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 Handlebars.registerHelper('p_available_options', function() {
   return JSON.stringify(this);
 });
</script>

<span id="spnEdit" onclick="openEditModel('{{p_available_options}}','{{p_id}}');">EDIT</span> 

The above code worked for me.. :) Thanks all :)
```